# Centering Text Within A Div (Wordpress Menu)

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, centering

I'm having a little trouble centering the menu items in my Wordpress theme. You can see the site here: http://tinyurl.com/k2aq3sh

I tried margin:auto but no dice. Here is the current CSS:

```
#primary-menu-container {
 margin-bottom:-27px;
  margin-top:-10px;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  max-width:1020px;

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to center the whole menu in the nav bar, do it like this:

```
#primary-menu {
list-style: none;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to remove the floating of the #primary-menu-container div and the list items. Instead add display:inline-block to the list items and from there you can add text-align:center to the ul element

```
#primary-menu-container {
    ...
    float:none
}

#primary-menu{
    ...
    text-align:center;
}

#primary-menu li, .default-menu li {
    ...
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Erik, thanks for the response. Tried that change, cleared the cache and the menu still remains to the left.

Comment: Check that none of the properties gets overridden somehow, I tried this with inspect element and got it to work.